# Does consteval function can be called with an unused empty class object as an object?

Tags: c++, c++20, consteval

The following code:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    consteval auto operator+(Foo) const noexcept {
        return Foo{};
    }
};

struct Bar : Foo {};

Foo func() {
    Bar foo, bar;
    return foo + bar;
}
```

, in which `Foo` is an empty class, can be compiled with GCC and Clang, but not with MSVC.

MSVC says `bar` is not a constant expression so it cannot be the argument of the immediate function`operator+`. But GCC and Clang don't think so.

Then which compiler is correct?

Diff view in Compiler Explorer:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o95oK81vn

Comment: please incldue the compiler error message in the question rather than paraphrasing it

Comment: Diff view in Compiler Explorer:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o95oK81vn

Comment: why do you not include it in the question? ... hm... nevermind. I will include it in the answer

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to include it in the question and there are too many pending edits on stackoverflow so that I cannot edit this question now 

Comment: Here is the description to pending edits: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/why-does-the-suggested-edit-queue-have-a-fixed-size-and-what-is-its-size-on-eac  Now it has released. I've added it into the question, yeah.

Comment: ah ok, Sorry for assuming the worst. Thanks for the link

Comment: sorry for insisting but I really meant to include the message in the question, not just a link. Links can break and questions should be selfcontained, if possible, all information should be 0 clicks away. It is possible here.

Comment: `return Bar{} + Bar{};` works in MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a MSVC bug to me. I don't see any reason that the invocation shouldn't be a constant expression.

In particular `bar` is not accessed outside its lifetime.